# notification launch custom method/class

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, localnotification

just want to make sure i'm on the right path.

I'm creating a local notification as an alarm clock.  when the user hits button... I want it to DO STUFF.

I'm thinking I have to call my method in

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  .. .for when the application is closed
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
  ... for when the application is in the background... when user hits okay

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish... DO STUFF when user hits okay on notification?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of local and push notifications, you should call `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in both cases :

> Handling Local and Remote Notifications
>
> Let’s review the possible scenarios when the operating delivers a
>   local notification or a remote notification for an application.
>
> The notification is delivered when the application isn’t running in the foreground.
>   In this case, the system presents the notification, displaying an alert, badging an icon, perhaps playing a sound.
>   As a result of the presented notification, the user taps the action button of the alert or taps (or clicks) the application icon.
>
> If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the application and the application calls its
>   delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if
>   implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote
>   notifications) or the local-notification object (for local
>   notifications).
>   If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about
>   the notification .

Answer (score 1):

They can not be forced to call. only Monitoring.

> **UIApplicationDelegate Protocol**
>
> These methods provide you with information about key events in an
>   application’s execution such as when it finished launching, when it is
>   about to be terminated, when memory is low, and when important changes
>   occur. Implementing these methods gives you a chance to respond to
>   these system events and respond appropriately.

If you want you're ViewController get Notification there method. try this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidFinishLaunching:) UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)noti
{
    //do stuff
}

- (void)applicationEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)noti
{
    //do sutff
}
```